# How to read text file and convert it to a Dataset in Java Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I want to read in two text files with data and run some machine learning classification on the data in my Java Spark project

Let `fileZero`  and `fileOne` be two files containing the data in the following form

```
>fileZero
10 1 
9.8 1.2 
10.1 0.9
....
```

And the other file

```
>fileOne
0.1 40 
0.2 38 
0 50
...
```

For `fileZero` and `fileOne` each line contains a (x,y) tuple separated by a space and is labeled labeled 0 and 1 respectively. In other words all rows in `fileZero` are supposed to be labelled 0 and for `fileOne` 1.

I want to read in  both files and was thinking of using the object `Dataset`. 
How can read in the two files that later I can run classifation/ logistic regression on the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the pojo object and read the files into object.

MyObject

```
public class MyObject {
private double x;
private double y;
private double label;
//Getters and setters
...
}
```

You can read and convert files to dataset like this :

```
JavaRDD<MyObject> cRDD = spark.read().textFile("C:/Temp/File0.csv").javaRDD()
                       .map(new Function<String, MyObject>() {
                              @Override
                              public MyObject call(String line) throws Exception {
                                     String[] parts = line.split(" ");
                                     MyObject c = new MyObject();
                                     c.setX(parts[0].trim());
                                     c.setY(parts[1].trim());                                   
                                     c.setLabel(0);
                                     return c;
                              }
                       });


          Dataset<Row> mainDataset = spark.createDataFrame(cRDD, MyObject.class);
```

and then you can use classification methods...